# Mysql Multiple users using diff diff SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS leads to diff diff total row count

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have used multiple various queries in our system where we want to fetch "total" records for pagination things.

All places I have followed the kind of structure -

```
var query1 = "select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ...."
sql.query(query1, [], function (error, results, fields) {
 var _qry2 = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total;"
                    sql.query(_qry2, [], function (error2, results2, fields2) {
 });
});
```

The problem I am facing here is that when 1-10 users are my using my all of the system, it gives correct "total" count for all APIs.

But when the no. of users increases to more than 10 say 20, The "total" count keeps changing as each users using one of APIs from all.

So say if the "total" rows in 245, sometimes it gives me 18, sometimes 300 and sometimes 245 based on other queries "total" count.

I don't know what is happening here, totally blank.

Need help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the same connection to get a reliable result, not just one from the pool.

```
sql.getConnection(function(err, conn) {
    if (err) throw err;
    conn.query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table", [], function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            conn.release(); // give connection back to the pool
            throw err;
        }
        conn.query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total", [], function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                conn.release(); // give connection back to the pool
                throw err;
            }
            let total = result[0].total;
            conn.release();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a concurrency issue. `FOUND_ROWS()` returns the number of rows returned for the last executed select statement.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

> The row count available through FOUND_ROWS() is transient and not
>   intended to be available past the statement following the SELECT
>   SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS statement.

As your number of users increases, so does the probability of another `SELECT` statement being executed between the initial `SELECT` and your execution of `FOUND_ROWS()`

Comment: What is the solution then?